# How to highlight only image without whole region in c#?

Tags: c#, image, highlight

I want to make highlight image like it was in Google apps (google g+ in html) when is highlighted only image (without boundary border, whole region) when mouse is on it.

In c# i use images to do that, but every time when i get with mouse to the images it highlight  me all region (boundary border + image).

So now my question is: **How to highlight only images without whole region?**

Picture show that C# APPS highlight image and also whole region (gray rectangle).
 **How to bypass those gray rectangle?**

[image]

More details: Framework 4.5 or higher, WinForms, Win7 
It's not necessarily that application use image control if other control do that in smarter way ... please let me know ...

Comment: What UI framework are you using? WinForms? WPF? WebForms? Something else?

Comment: Framework is 4.5 or higher, apps is winForms

Comment: And are these PictureBox controls you're using to display the images?

Comment: It can be anything ... what ever just to work ...i first use button and put tab options to false but have problem with color .. it can be PictureBox

Comment: Probably not the best solution but you could use a label and change the border style

Comment: You could, but making a Label control (or a PictureBox control) respond to clicks and receive the focus is more difficult than customizing the appearance of a Button control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Button control, like you said you already have, is a good start. You need a Button in order for the images to be focusable and clickable. A PictureBox doesn't support either of those things. You could obviously write the code to handle those things manually, but there's no point since Button already has it built in. So now the battle just becomes customizing the Button control to do what you want.

It also looks like from your screenshot that you've already figured out that you need to handle the `Enter` and `Leave` events in order to change the image from the "normal" state to the "hot" state, and then back again. And to get the appearance you want, you've set the Button's `FlatStyle` property to `FlatStyle.Flat` and the `FlatAppearance.BorderSize` property to 0.

So the only problem is that a focus cue is getting drawn around the Button control when it has the focus. Normally, you would *want* this, because someone who navigates your app with the keyboard needs some way to figure out which control currently has the focus. But you're giving them one by changing the image it displays, so you can safely disable these focus cues. The way to do that is by inheriting from the Button class and overriding the [`ShowFocusCues` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.showfocuscues.aspx).

Add a new code file to your project that contains the following class declaration:

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
   public ImageButton()
   {
      // Set default properties.
      this.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
      this.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
   }

   protected override bool ShowFocusCues
   {
      get  { return false; }
   }
}
```

Then, use the `ImageButton` class for your button controls, instead of the built-in `Button` class. Controls of this type will automatically have the behavior you desire.

[image]

If you need even more control over the appearance of your custom button, you can override its [`OnPaint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint.aspx) method. Skip calling the base class implementation if you don't want any of the default behavior. For example, we could simply erase the button's background and draw its image:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pevent)
{
   // do not call the base class implementation
   // base.OnPaint(e);

   // erase the background
   pevent.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Control, this.ClientRectangle);

   // draw the image at the top-left
   pevent.Graphics.DrawImage(this.Image, Point.Empty);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Cody ... you always help me when is most needed :)